# Replace default copy constructor with copy constructor for base class (c++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor, base-class

I have an abstract class list:

```
template <class V>
class List {
public:
  void toArray(void*) const = 0;
// other methods
};
```

And I have an inherited class arraylist:

```
template <class V>
class ArrayList:
  public List<V>
{
public:
  ArrayList(const List<V>&);
  void toArray(void*) const;
private:
  ArrayList(const ArrayList&); //Remove default copy ctor
// other methods and functions
};
```

When calling `ArrayList(const ArrayList&)` I would like to use the constructor for `ArrayList(const List&)`.

```
LinkedList<int> link; // also inherited from list
// populate list
ArrayList<int> lst = link; // works fine
ArrayList<int> newList = lst; // error ctor is private
```

I would not like to rewrite the code in `ArrayList(const List&)` for `ArrayList(const ArrayList&)` because they both use the same `toArray(void*)` method declared in `List`. How do I do this? I would also like to avoid calling the default ctor of `ArrayList` because it allocates a minimum sized array of 8 values.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Use websites like Facebook, Blogger or Twitter for status updates. Use Stack Overflow to *ask questions*.

Comment: `// error ctor is private`: Yes, you made it private. You could either omit specification of the copy constructor at all, or provide another public signature explicitly for `List`: `ArrayList(const List&)`

Comment: If I simply omit the specification of the copy constructor then the default copy constructor is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template <class V>
class ArrayList: public List<V>
{
public:
  ArrayList(const List<V>&);

  // use delegating constructor (C++11 feature)
  ArrayList(const ArrayList& val) : ArrayList( static_cast<const List<V>&>(val) ) {}

  void toArray(void*) const;
private:
};
```

If your compiler does not support C++11:

```
template <class V>
class ArrayList: public List<V>
{
public:
  ArrayList(const List<V>& val) { construct(val;) }
  ArrayList(const ArrayList& val) { construct(val;) }
  void toArray(void*) const;
private:
  void construct(const List<V>&);
};
```

Comment: I like the simple solution! I knew about the delegating constructor but I was trying to avoid it so I will use your second solution. Thank you very much Dmitry!